# Managing video stream buffering in Android VideoView

Tags: android, video-streaming

My requirement is:
1. Get the video mp4/3gp file from url(web service call)
2. play the video continuously without buffering while playing.

for this what is the best process?

i have two ideas i.e
1. Download the full video into sdcard, then read it and play using Android VideoView.
2. Stream the total video and play it
   Note: suppose i have 10mb video file .

which is the best one or is there any other way?

and please tell the process for streaming?

please help on this ?

Comment: Depending on the speed of your connecting it may be enough to just download a part of the file before starting to play it

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);

mVideoView.setVideoPath("url");
mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String SrcPath="http://akamedia2.lsops.net/live/smil:cnbc_en.smil/playlist.m3u8";
        myVideoView = new VideoView(this);
        myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(SrcPath));
        setContentView(myVideoView);
        myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
```

Try this code. Hope its helpful to you.